# Importing error from eclipse to android studio

Tags: android, eclipse

I am importing eclipse project, and project has some libraries like googleplay service, google uri auth and parse. Now I am importing an eclipse project in android studio but I am facing an error. I had tried cleaning the project and all the things that is required but I didn't get the reply. Below is my error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':weddinhHall:dexDebug'.
>   > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 2

and my build.gradle file is like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxxxxx.main"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }

    }

}


dependencies {

    compile project(':parallaxScroll')
    compile project(':googleDateTimePickers')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.10.3-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.10.3-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.10.1-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')


}
```

Has anyone met this issue before?

Answer (score 1):

Please remove `compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')` . `dexDebug` occurs when duplicate entry happen . You already initialize google play service `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'.`

FYI: Please use latest google play service version , like `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'`